# Parsing Generics with Spring Expression Language(SpEL)

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-el

How to parse generics expression using SpEL?

```
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
String queryString = "new List<Integer>()";
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(queryString);
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) exp.getValue(context);
```

It's throwing exception. SpEL allows to parse arbitrary expression.
What am I missing here?

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1050E:(pos 8): The arguments (...) for the constructor call are missing
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatConstructorArgs(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:450)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatConstructorReference(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:792)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatStartNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:507)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPrimaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:343)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatUnaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:337)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPowerIncDecExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:293)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatProductExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:272)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatSumExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:255)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatRelationalExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:210)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatLogicalAndExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatLogicalOrExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:186)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:146)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:127)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:76)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:62)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Inline list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-lists) SpEL ability:

```
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
String queryString = "{1,2,3}";
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(queryString);
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) exp.getValue(context);
int one = list.get(0);
```

Alternatively, you can define your list in [SpEL context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-type-conversion).

Comment: My use case is little different.                       DynamoDBQueryExpression<User> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<User>().withHashKeyValues(carter);
  DynamoDBQueryExpression<User> req = (DynamoDBQueryExpression<User>) exp.getValue(context)

Comment: @PremKumar then use : `String queryString = "{}";`

Comment: Ok..This is my simplest query string. String queryString = "new DynamoDBQueryExpression<T(User)>().withHashKeyValues(#attr1)";

Comment: It works fine when no generics involved. e.g. it works perfectly fine. String deleteTableString = "new com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DeleteTableRequest().withTableName(#tableName)";

Comment: @PremKumar SpEL does not support generic parameters.

Comment: SpEL is not Java its a different language that doesn't have generics. In any case, even with java, the type is erased from the runtime.

Comment: Thanks all for help:)

Answer (score 0):

SpEL is too good to ignore. So I ended up solving this problem as follows:

Due to Java type eraser, it doesn't really matter whether following function returns - DynamoDBQueryExpression< User> or DynamoDBQueryExpression< Object>. Both are same at runtime.

```
public class DynamoDBQueryExpressionGenerics {
    public static DynamoDBQueryExpression<?> get(){
        return new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Object>();
    }
}


    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.setVariable("attr", prem);
    String queryString = "T(DynamoDBQueryExpressionGenerics).get().withHashKeyValues(#attr)";
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(queryString);
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<User> req = (DynamoDBQueryExpression<User>) exp.getValue(context);
    System.out.println(req);
    PaginatedList<User> r = mapper.query(User.class, req);
    for(User u : r){
        System.out.println("Query Expression : " + u.getFirstName() + " : " + u.getLastName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(myList);

context.setVariable("myList", myList);

List<Integer> newList = parser.parseExpression("#myList").getValue(context, List.class);
```